# SQLite and MySQL

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm working on an android application for my final year project. My app is about storing information and then display it out on the phone.

I figure it out by using sqlite, I'm able to store data in it, as well as retrieve it by using cursor `c`. But how am I able to make the retrieve data visible to the user?

- example: I'm creating an app about Burger King, and I click the information about Burger King, it shows the information (when was is created etc) to the user.

Answer (score 0):

This is kind of an open-ended question.  If you want to present your search results to the user as a list or a grid, then use a ListView or a Gridview, and attach a CursorAdapter to your View.  The CursorAdapter will read the results out of the database and provide them to the View.  You'll probably want to subclass your CursorAdapter so that it generates the appropriate views for your ListView/GridView to display.

It's kind of an advanced topic, but I'm sure you can find tutorials and code samples.

If you just want to display a single data item on the screen (presumably a data item with a lot of detail), then you'll probably want to define a Dialog or Activity to present it to the user, and then read the data from the cursor and load it into the various View objects in your Dialog/Activity.

I hope this helps.  It would be useful if we knew more detail about what you're trying to do.

Comment: I'm trying to create an apps that will display the history of certain places. For example like this [link](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=sg.codigo.brasbasah&hl=en) It is something similar to this apps, if you would just click the 2nd apps screen shot. it will show the image of the place and tells you about the places information. if i were to store the information and image of a certain place in sqlite , how do i make it visible to the user? like in the 2nd screen shot. Hope this help on explaining more details on what im trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Edward Falk on the need for more clearly defined details. In answering your question I would suggest creating some TextViews or a ListView in your xml file like so:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent">
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/fragmentLayout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="8dp"
    android:paddingRight="8dp" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/viewl"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/viewvaluesLabel"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/view2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/viewvaluesLabel"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />


            .
            .
            .

</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

You can then get these TextViews by their respective ids using a "R.find" statement like:

```
TextView view1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.view1);
TextView view2 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.view2);
TextView view3 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.view3);
```

and then set the data you retrieve from your database table to display in these views using code like this:

```
Cursor c = db.getDetails(id);
if (c.moveToFirst()) {
view1.setText(c.getString(1));
view2.setText(c.getString(2));
view3.setText(c.getString(3));
} else {
    db.close();
}
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: I'm trying to create an apps that will display the history of certain places. For example like this [link](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=sg.codigo.brasbasah&hl=en) It is something similar to this apps, if you would just click the 2nd apps screen shot. it will show the image of the place and tells you about the places information. if i were to store the information and image of a certain place in sqlite , how do i make it visible to the user? like in the 2nd screen shot. Hope this help on explaining more details on what im trying to do.

Comment: I still suggest using a ListView with a custom adapter that lets you display images and text in the views. Here's a [link](http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-listview-example/) to a tutorial that's quite handy and should give you the general idea.